# Creating multiple row in Gridview without any addrow button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a table like this in Gridview in Asp.net
[image]

I used the below code to create this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid_Diagnosis" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="0"
                      CellSpacing="0" CssClass="rounded-corner" ShowFooter="true"  >

                        <Columns>

                          <asp:TemplateField>
                              <HeaderStyle CssClass="rounded" />
                              <ItemStyle />
                              <HeaderTemplate>
                                  P.T Notes
                              </HeaderTemplate>

                              <ItemTemplate>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_Ptnote1" runat="server" CssClass="input_text"></asp:TextBox>    
                                  <br />   
                                    <br />   
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_Ptnote2" runat="server" CssClass="input_text"></asp:TextBox>      
                                    <br />   
                                    <br />   
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_Ptnote3" runat="server" CssClass="input_text"></asp:TextBox>      
                                    <br />   
                                    <br />   
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_Ptnote4" runat="server" CssClass="input_text"></asp:TextBox>      
                                    <br />   
                                    <br />   
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_Ptnote5" runat="server" CssClass="input_text"></asp:TextBox>      
                                    <br />   
                                    <br />   
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_Ptnote6" runat="server" CssClass="input_text"></asp:TextBox>      
                                    <br />   
                                    <br />   
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_Ptnote7" runat="server" CssClass="input_text"></asp:TextBox>      

                              </ItemTemplate>
                          </asp:TemplateField>
                          <asp:TemplateField>
                              <HeaderStyle />
                              <HeaderTemplate>
                                  Notes Goal
                              </HeaderTemplate>
                              <ItemStyle />
                              <ItemTemplate>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_notesgoal1" runat="server" CssClass="input_text"></asp:TextBox>       
                                   <br />   
                                    <br />   
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_notesgoal2" runat="server" CssClass="input_text"></asp:TextBox>      
                                    <br />   
                                    <br />   
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_notesgoal3" runat="server" CssClass="input_text"></asp:TextBox>      
                                    <br />   
                                    <br />   
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_notesgoal4" runat="server" CssClass="input_text"></asp:TextBox>      
                                    <br />   
                                    <br />   
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_notesgoal5" runat="server" CssClass="input_text"></asp:TextBox>      
                                    <br />   
                                    <br />   
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_notesgoal6" runat="server" CssClass="input_text"></asp:TextBox>      
                                    <br />   
                                    <br />   
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_notesgoal7" runat="server" CssClass="input_text"></asp:TextBox>      

                              </ItemTemplate>
                          </asp:TemplateField>
                      </Columns>
                  </asp:GridView>
```

I got the table like the Picture above.But the problem is that on saving the data in each textbox to the database table,I want to take control of all textbox and also insert the data 1 row at a time.It take too lengthy code.

So I want to know Is there any alternative way to create the table like this in gridview without adding multiple textbox like that?

Note:I know add a new row anytime when click the Button(add row) method is possible ,but i can't use that method in my project.

Thanks

Comment: i really don't understand what you are trying to do. If saving the data is the whole purpose why not DataBind ? also you can use a list of Textbox like List<TextBox> myTextboxList

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I quite understand what you want but you can use something like this to read each cell content(including controls) on a specific row.

```
for (int j = 0; j < Grid_Diagnosis.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)    
{
     TextBox In_Cell_TextBox = 
         (Label)Grid_Diagnosis.Rows[i].Cells[j].FindControl("Txt_notesgoal"+j);

     String myTextBoxText =  In_Cell_TextBox.Text;    
}
```